# String to array - array with only one index (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, string, indexing, explode

I have this string:

```
$string = "123456789"
```

It should become an array:

```
Array ( [0] => 123 ) Array ( [1] => 456 ) Array ( [2] => 789 )
```

but I get:

```
Array ( [0] => 123 ) Array ( [0] => 456 ) Array ( [0] => 789 )
```

I use loop to get this string:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
{
    $string = $tree['a']['b'][$i]['c'];
}
```

Next I use explode function to get an array. Why I got the array with only one index - zero? What I should do to get:

```
 Array ( [0] => 123 ) Array ( [1] => 456 ) Array ( [2] => 789 ).
```

Please help me understand this.

Comment: What generates the output you publish here? What is `$tree`? What is ` $string` ?

Comment: I parse xml file. I got data in a tree structure (multi-dimensional Array).

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_split($string, 3)` to create the array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

Comment: Thanks but I got the same (array with only one index).

Comment: the function str_split should work `$arr = str_split($string, 3);`